# Distance between kinect camera and trcked skeleton

Tags: c#-4.0, kinect

Is there any way to find out the distance between the Kinect camera and the tracked skeleton using the Kinect 1.6 sdk??? 
I want to get how long the skeleton is from the Kinect camera?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for the `Z` value of any `SkeletonPoint` will give you the distance from the Kinect of that `Joint` in meters.  Getting the `Z` value from the `Depth` will give you distance to that pixel in millimeters.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx